# Can't display array output

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(){

    var word = document.getElementById("inp").value;
    var letters = [];
    for(i=0; i<=word.length; i++){
        letters = word.substring(i,i+1);
    }
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = letters[0];

    //setInterval();
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="inp" />
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<br>
<div id="div"></div>

</body>
```

The output of "letters[0]" is showing up as undefined.
I want to create an array, where, let's say if the input was "hello", then, output would be like:

```
letters[0] = "h"
letters[1] = "e"
letters[2] = "l"
....
```

And also, I would like to add a setInterval() function to it, so that it displays the letters, one by one, with a delay.

Thanks!

Comment: Another thing: `i<=word.length` can’t be right. It’s supposed to be `i<word.length`, because it will go over the last index of the string. This doesn’t throw an error when using `substring`, because it will simply return an empty string. Be aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `push` method to add elements in the array

Replace

```
letters = word.substring(i,i+1);
```

by

```
letters.push(word.substring(i,i+1));
```

**Demo**

```js
function show() {
  var word = document.getElementById("inp").value;

  var letters = [];
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    letters.push(word.substring(i, i + 1));
  }

  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = letters[i];
    ++i === letters.length && clearInterval(interval);
  }, 250);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<br>
<div id="div"></div>
```

---

To get the array of individual letters you can also use `split`

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div"); // Cache

function show() {
  var word = document.getElementById("inp").value; // Get latest value

  var letters = word.split(''), // Split every character and store in letters array
    i = 0; // Initialization to zero

  div.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous text

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    div.innerHTML += letters[i]; // Append a character

    ++i === letters.length && clearInterval(interval); // Clear interval after appending all the characters
  }, 100); // Call the function after every 100 milliseconds
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<br>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: why not `var letters = word.split('');`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for helping me improve answer

Comment: So you're setting var interval = "something", but how are you calling it? What i mean to say is that why won't something like this work:

Comment: @ImranNiloy The `setInterval` function is called immedietly, the return value i.e. interval id is cached in the variable which is used for clearing interval later

Comment: `code`
for(i=0; i<word.length; ++i){
          
           setInterval(function(){
         document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = letters[i];
     }, 1000);
          
    }

Comment: @ImranNiloy That won't work, if you want something like that use `for (i = 0; i < word.length; ++i) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = letters[i];
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000 * i);
}`

Comment: @Tushar What is the implication of the  "1000 * i" in the end?

Comment: @ImranNiloy If you use `1000` for all the timeouts, all the characters will be shown at once and you will see only last character, by multiplying it by `i` will set the gap of `1000` milliseconds between showing two characters, try to run it with and without `* i` and you'll see the difference

Answer (score 1):

Don't overwrite the value of `letters` in each iteration. Append to the Array object using `push`.

```
function show(){

    var word = document.getElementById("inp").value;
    var letters = [];
    for(i=0; i<=word.length; i++){
        letters.push(word.substring(i,i+1))
    }
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = letters[0];

    //setInterval();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are overriding the value of `letters` instead of creating it as an array

```js
var interval, i;

function show() {

  var word = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var letters = word.split('');

  clearInterval(interval); //clear the previos interval
  i = 0; //start from the first index
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = letters[i];
    i = ++i < word.length ? i : 0; //if the last char is shown start from beginning
  }, 500);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<br>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only problem with the code is assign letters either using push method of array or using indexing:

```js
function show() {

  var word = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var letters = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
    letters[i] = word.substring(i, i + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = letters[0];
}

//setInterval();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<br>
<div id="div"></div>
```